# Get average rating from a Super Search results set

Tags: stash, supersearch, query, solspace-rating, query-module

I have a series of super search results listing pages displaying lists that are all rated with the Ratings module.

I want to get the average rating of *all* the entries in the list to put into schema markup (as opposed to the average rating for each entry which is what the `exp:rating:stats` tag would do).

I thought I could do it with the query module because I've used it for a similar case elsewhere on the site, except that there it's working out the average of all the ratings on the *site*, not just those from a particular page.

I can save the list of IDs to a variable with Stash:

```
  {exp:super_search:results}
        {exp:stash:append_list
              name='ids'
              context="@URI"
        }{stash:id}{entry_id},{/stash:id}{/exp:stash:append_list}
  {/exp:super_search:results}
```

which outputs as expected, i.e. `1,2,3` etc. but if I try to input that into a query like

```
  {exp:query
        sql="SELECT count(entry_id) as `count`, avg(rating) as `avg` FROM exp_ratings WHERE entry_id IN ({exp:stash:get_list
        name='ids'
        backspace='1'
        process='end'
        context='@URI'
  }{id}{/exp:stash:get_list})"
        parse='inward'
  }
 {/query}
```

I get a WSOD.

I've also tried the above with all the line breaks removed.

If I replace the `get_list` in the query with the actual values that the list outputs if used outside the `query`, e.g.

```
  {exp:query
        sql="SELECT count(entry_id) as `count`, avg(rating) as `avg` FROM exp_ratings WHERE entry_id IN (1,2,3)"
        parse='inward'
  }
 {/query}
```

I get the expected output. So the query itself is fine, it's just trying to use a dynamic Stash variable which seems to be causing the WSOD.

Does anyone have suggestions as to how I could accomplish the task?

Comment: What version of EE?  Perhaps closing the `exp:query` tag will clear WSOD?   If you can get to point where you don't have WSOD you can see the SQL being submitted to `exp:query` listed in the debug output, so if it is still not giving correct results you can at least see what SQL is being submitted.

Comment: I've edited the question to add some more detail. The closing tag is there, I hadn't included it in the question. EE version is 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more searching I found that passing variables into EE's query module to be problematic with a lot of workarounds using PHP variables or plugins instead.

So I wrote a quick plugin to handle the query and ended up doing this in the template:

```
{exp:stash:parse process='end'}
  <script type='application/ld+json'>
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "CollectionPage",
    "aggregateRating": {
      "@type": "AggregateRating",
      "ratingCount": "{super_search_total_results}",
      "ratingValue": "{exp:td_tours_average_rating ids="{exp:stash:get_list name='st_schema_ids' backspace='1' context='@URI'}{schema_id}{/exp:stash:get_list}" parse="inward"}"
    }
  }
  </script>
  {/exp:stash:parse}
```